# How do you validate the token is correct in an app launched from a main app?

Tags: c#, reactjs, cryptography, identityserver4

We want to build a main React App which after login shows a number of apps (list of apps the users has access to once authenticated). When the user clicks on one of the apps, the token from the main app is sent to the other app.

How will the second app know the token is valid?
Do the apps need to be on the same domain for this to work?
Also each app will have its own authorization (i.e. what the user can do in each app), would the token contain all this information or can we get this latter for each app using the same token?

Sorry for the large number of questions.

I am new to identity server and openID connect so any pointers would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should not pass tokens between your apps. All of your apps should be separate `client`, but the common thing they will have is the same central authority url (your identity server) that they would use to retrieve tokens. This would all be seamless from user's point of view due to the single sign on achieved on the central authority using cookie authentication - once the user logs in to your main app, whenever other apps redirect user to get the token, they will bypass login page due to cookie auth and would go directly into consent page (can also skip consent page via setting client property `RequireConsent` to false which is commonly done for first party apps).

To answer some of your questions:

> How will the second app know the token is valid?

Well this is not really needed if you don't pass around token between apps, but technically it could verify the token via its signature or using introspection endpoint.

> Do the apps need to be on the same domain for this to work?

They don't have to be on same domain.

> would the token contain all this information or can we get this latter
>   for each app using the same token?

The claims that the token contains is largely controlled based on the scope that the client requests (at least by default). So if you have each app requesting their own token, then it would have to request all the scopes that it is interested on. A lot of this behaviour can be overridden and extended due to the insane flexibility of Identity Server 4 so almost always you will have a way to accomplish what you want.